# Clustered chart tweak using pandas and xlsxwriter library

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I went through the following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
from vincent.colors import brews

# Some sample data to plot.
farm_1 = {'April': 7, 'July': 98, 'June': 124, 'May': 47}
farm_2 = {'April': 7, 'July': 4, 'June': 34, 'May': 45}
farm_3 = {'April': 4, 'July': 5, 'June': 6, 'May': 12}

data  = [farm_1, farm_2, farm_3]
index = ['Farm 1', 'Farm 2', 'Farm 3']

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
writer     = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_chart_columns.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Some alternative colors for the chart.
colors = ['#E41A1C', '#377EB8', '#4DAF4A', '#984EA3', '#FF7F00']

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
for col_num in range(1, len(farm_1) + 1):
    chart.add_series({
        'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, col_num],
        'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 4, 0],
        'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, col_num, 4, col_num],
        'fill':       {'color':  colors[col_num - 1]},
        'overlap':    -10,
    })

# Configure the chart axes.
chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Total Produce'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Farms', 'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('H2', chart)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

It outputs data as:
[Please see screenshot here](https://snag.gy/VT1bdm.jpg)

I want it to look like the one highlighted in green.

I tried changing the  chart.add_series but I have been not successful.

I am a newbie with pandas and xlsxwriter library, still trying to learn.

Any pointers or help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do the same as you did in Excel, i.e., switch the categories and values in the data source. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data to plot.
farm_1 = {'April': 7, 'July': 98, 'June': 124, 'May': 47}
farm_2 = {'April': 7, 'July': 4, 'June': 34, 'May': 45}
farm_3 = {'April': 4, 'July': 5, 'June': 6, 'May': 12}

data  = [farm_1, farm_2, farm_3]
index = ['Farm 1', 'Farm 2', 'Farm 3']

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
writer     = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_chart_columns.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
min_col = 1  # Start from Col B.
max_col = min_col + len(farm_1) -1
name_col = 0
series_row = 0

for row_num in range(1, len(data) + 1):
    chart.add_series({
        'name':       ['Sheet1', row_num, name_col],
        'categories': ['Sheet1', series_row, min_col, series_row, max_col],
        'values':     ['Sheet1', row_num, min_col, row_num, max_col],
    })

# Configure some other chart setting to get the desired output.
chart.set_legend({'position': 'bottom'})
chart.set_y_axis({'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('G2', chart)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

This gives the desired output:

[image]

Note, I've turned the category and value ranges into variables so if your dataset is different the chart will adjust.

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

I left the colors as the default ones given in excel to make the solution a bit simpler.  Other than that I produced the desired chart provided in your link.

I used the xl_rowcol_to_cell() function from the XlsxWriter utility module (link [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions)) with chart.add_series.

Full code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

# Some sample data to plot.
farm_1 = {'April': 7, 'July': 98, 'June': 124, 'May': 47}
farm_2 = {'April': 7, 'July': 4, 'June': 34, 'May': 45}
farm_3 = {'April': 4, 'July': 5, 'June': 6, 'May': 12}

data  = [farm_1, farm_2, farm_3]
index = ['Farm 1', 'Farm 2', 'Farm 3']

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
writer     = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_chart_columns.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

for col_num in range (1, 4):
    cell_1 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(col_num, 0)
    cell_2 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(col_num, 1)
    cell_3 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(col_num, 4)  
    chart.add_series({
        'categories': "='Sheet1'!$B$1:$E$1",
        'name': "='Sheet1'!%s" % (cell_1),  
        'values': "='Sheet1'!%s:%s" % (cell_2, cell_3),
        'overlap':    -10,
    })

chart.set_legend({
    'position': 'bottom',
})  

# Configure the chart axes.
chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Total Produce'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Farms',})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('H2', chart)

writer.save()
```